# How to connect static HTML and CSS files to Node.js application?

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku

I try to show a (static) HTML webpage via Heroku. I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAwH1kSODVQ but after many attempts it is still not working.

I'm rather new to coding, so if you can give concrete examples that would be great!

The following files have been pushed to heroku:

```
server.js 
package.json
Procfile.js
(folder) public with index.html, main.css
```

//Server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'); //require express module in server.js file
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('birthdaylist', ['birthdaylist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //connect to html file
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/birthdaylist', function(req, res) {
  console.log("The server has received a GET request.")
  db.birthdaylist.find(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.post('/birthdaylist', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  db.birthdaylist.insert(req.body, function (err, doc){
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.delete('/birthdaylist/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.birthdaylist.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc){
    res.json(doc);
  });
});


app.listen(port, function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
app.listen(%PORT_NUMBER%, function () {
  // some code here
});
```

Instead of:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.end('<h6>Hello worldsfasfd!</h6>');
});
```

Comment: It worked, but when I refreshed the page I get an Application error. I have updated my code (see above).

Comment: I tried to access http://tue2id60.herokuapp.com (if you go to that site you'll see the error")

Comment: It looks like there was a problem during the heroku deployment. did you get any errors? try to look at the logs

Comment: The only error I can find is "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL = error"

Comment: Does it work localy? What exactly did you update in your code? Try to redeploy.

Comment: Failed at the 2id60@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2015-12-22T13:55:16.620092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2015-12-22T13:55:16.620884+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-12-22T13:55:16.621041+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls 2id60
2015-12-22T13:55:16.621200+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: I have used
    app.listen(port, function() {

});
 
instead of: 

    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.end('<h6>Hello worldsfasfd!</h6>');
});

Comment: Did you run this on your local machine ?

Comment: It has anything to do with node.js or express. Did you start your app on heroku? was the deployment successful?

Comment: Locally it works fine. What do you mean with "have you started your app on heroku". I have updated the server.js file and then pushed it (git push heroku master).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its different with nodejs. try executing 'heroku local web'

Comment: Your app is crashing on enter. As I said, it's not related to the question, but do the following: deploy, then run 'heroku logs --tail'. then open your app, you should see errors in the log (refresh if not). Anyway, add 'try-catch' to all your methods